# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created using Selenium Java with a downloaded chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge

When I try to start a new Microsoft Edge session, I encounter this error:

> Unknown Problem: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created
> from no such execution context: loader has changed while resolving nodes
> (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=114.0.1823.79)
> System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.15'
> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver

I have already researched this specific error, and the only solution I found was to add these two arguments:

> --disable-dev-shm-usage
> --remote-allow-origins=*

and to add this setting:

> System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "driverpath");

which I have already done.

Edit:
This problem only occurs in our CI, and it happens kind of randomly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to handle drivers version / installation automatically, I suggest to use Webdriver manager like [this](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)

You can simply add dependency to `pom.xml`

```html
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

[Reference](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)

And then use code like

```js
public class SiteTest extends BaseTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupAll() {
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
    }

    @Test
    public void openSite() {
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.get("https://example.com");
    }
}
```

If this would work for you - so issue with session was in driver compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider a couple of things:

- Upgrade to [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** or above so [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) can automatically download the matching EdgeDriver. So you can remove

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "driverpath");
  ```
- `--remote-allow-origins=*` is no more mandatory with Chrome and [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) *version: 114.0*. So you can drop it.
- [*`disable-dev-shm-usage`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76615980/7429447)  isn't effective unless you are using the [*`--no-sandbox`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71699916/7429447) argument. So you can drop it.

Making the above mentioned adjustments execute your code.